# Is there a function that saves the last value inputted with query?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

```
=IF(Summary!H2="October",QUERY(Summary!L2))
```

Hello,

I was wondering if it’s possible to record the last inputted value with a query function

As seen in the code above, when October is selected in the summary sheet, cell H2 - the cell with the function (above) outputs what is written in the summary sheet, cell L2

When I select a different month, the cell (where the code is written) changes to FALSE

Is there any way to make value_if_false equal the last value inputted into L2 when the selected month is changed?

If further proof is needed please let me know

Thank you,
Gabe

Comment: What would be the purpose of retrieving the last value? Could you share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the expected output?

Comment: I’m creating a monthly budget spreadsheet where I can enter the correct balance in my account for each month - I want this data saved on a seperate sheet that I can refer back to when I change the month (all information is displayed on the main sheet but stored somewhere else) - if that makes sense

Comment: I want to be able to change the amount on the main page, then it updates on the data sheet and then when I change month on the main page it keeps the data so when I change back it’s the same

Comment: Range.getDisplayValue() would get the current value of that range.

Answer (score 0):

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX9IJ.png)

Don't know if this is what you mean, here I have created an example, where data is stored in the 'data' sheet, and the QUERY function is placed in the 'main' sheet.

B1, B2 is the condition inputs, I assume you want to sort your data by date, in that case, you will need a start day and an end day.

the QUERY formula will be something like this:

```
=QUERY({data!A:F},
 " WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL "
&" AND Col1 >= DATE '"&TEXT($B$1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' "
&" AND Col1 <= DATE '"&TEXT($B$2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' "
)
```

With this QUERY formula, the output data will change according to the date selected in B1 and B2.

Just make sure that the date column of your data page is formatted as date, otherwise google sheet QUERY will not be able to recognize the data as date.

[link of the sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WayD4GoQZ1tQrI3nRkbBQD8kCfP7cDW1R9Dz62-R110/edit?usp=sharing)